# Firebase database manage unregistered users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a project where I have to handle unregistered user - users that have been added to the group but still they do not have registered in the app.

What I'm doing now is to create a new child in my 'user' db, putting all the info that i know about this unregistered user. 
Of course, it also has an id.

This id will be used to represent that user and so it will be used in a lot of places of the db.

The problem comes when this user tries to register itself. Since when creating a new user it's not possible to force the 'id' that he already had, Firebase will create a new id for him.

Then, in the db I need to change all the references of the 'old id' with the new one.

Is there any better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use another "fake" table to remap the IDs, that is, instead of changing the old id and its references you can add new instance to your "fake" table when user registered. And when needed using simple service you can find the corresponding id.

2) Secondly, you can do authentication yourself, what I mean is that, you can develop your own registration service and define the id yourself in registration. If system is already big and hard to change. First option would be suitable but will have some cost in terms of time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Develop my own authentication system sounds too hard and too time consuming for that ask. 
I would go for the first option, I already thought about it, but this option would make things a lot worse when comes to look for a user with a specific id.
At the moment I just look into the user table querying for the user with the required id.
Using another table would mean , make the same query, and then check if there is an associated fake id and look again with that fake id.

Comment: Maybe , if this is the only option, it's better to develop some http function which will replace the old id with the new one.

Comment: Yeah, but problem is your structure, I would recommend to change your structure as soon as possible. Because it will get hard to do it after a while.

Comment: What do you mean the problem is my structure ? How would you change it?

Comment: I mean using the firebase registration service sometimes causes problems, as in your situation and I have experienced it also. Changing anything in your current structure without changing registration service will cost you maybe not too much but will be inefficient. However, if you could change your registration service you will not lose an efficiency but it just will take a time to develop. Maybe this is not a big problem for not but it can be a real problem in future if your system would get enough bigger.

Comment: I do not know your system and what it does so I cannot to perfect comment, but these are the possibilities.

Comment: Got it, you are may be right. Do you have some reference to build a custom auth system ? Or something already done that I can reuse ?

Comment: I depends what language you use, there are a lot of great examples of it that you can find by just little search.